# Cannot install openpyxl (ImportError: setuptools)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module, openpyxl

I am new to Python so sorry if the question is trivial. I need to work with python and Excel tables, therefore I was looking to install Openpyxl. I downloaded the .tar.gz pack and unizipped with Peazip, went to the terminal, set the directory to where the setup.py file is and run "py setup.py install". What I get is the following error:

```
C:\Python27\openpyxl>py setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 30, in <module>
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

I did not modify anything with the files I downloaded, this is the folder I am running the code in:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxPwM.png

What could the problem be?

Comment: The instructions clearly state that you should use `pip` to install the library.

Comment: This is such a wholesome post. Nothing difficult, no rambling explanations. Just a noob who couldn't make a connection between error and fix. And someone helps him out with a few helpful words. I doubt many people will see this, but I feel like I witnessed a sweet moment in someone's programming life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that setuptools is not installed on your system, try installing it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: Yes that was the problem apparently. I installed setuptools and now I managed to install openpyxl, it works. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try this first: `pip install setuptools`, and then try to install what you want.

Comment: Thank you in the end I managed to solve the problem by installing setuptools as you suggested me. Anyway I tried to run the line you wrote above but it seems "pip" was not recognized as a console command. What might have been the problem?

Comment: `pip.py` is situated in the `Scripts` directory which is in Pythons installation directory. Maybe it is here `C:\Python27\Scripts\`. So, first you can find where the pip.py is and change to this directory and try it or you can add this directory to the Path variable and try.